# reading crossword puzzle txt file

Tags: java, puzzle

I am new at JAVA and i got no idea how to start this. I was looking for a good start. I need to read a txt file that has a certain format and put it into a view. i first need to read the dimensions of the grid, then the words in the order of the puzzle, then the amount of words needed to be found and last the actual word. If anyone can get me into the right direction with an example, that would really help.
this is the format of the txt file

```
5 5 
abcd
dfad
adfe
lkjl
ekkf
5
realword
realword
realword
realword
realword
```

EDIT: so this is what i tried after testing to read out the file which works (thanks!). but i get stuk here, i still need to change from char[][] to box[][], since i will be needing it to fill the letterGrid.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Puzzle {

    //Box[][] letterGrid;
    char[][] letterGrid;
    List<Word> wordList;
    List<Box> wordInWording;

    public Puzzle() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("..\\word.txt"));

            String[] dimensions = br.readLine().split(" ");
            letterGrid = new char[Integer.parseInt(dimensions[0])][Integer.parseInt(dimensions[1])];

            for (int i = 0; i < letterGrid[0].length; i++) {
                String val = br.readLine();
                letterGrid[i]= val.toCharArray();
            }
            //while something something
int r = br.read();
        int c = br.read();
        letterGrid = new char[r][c];

        for (int i = 0; i<r; i++){
            String getChar = new String(br.readLine());
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
                letterGrid[i][j] = getChar.charAt(j);
            }
        }

//          String sCurrentLine;
//          while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
//              System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
//          }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: I added something, but i can't seem to get the logic behind the ints then the chars then the int then the strings

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good Start:

I will just give you hint on how to read lines from a text file. YOu have to build the logic on your own after reading from it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

You are not supposed to post such questions in SO without even giving it a try. Try to code, if you get stuck post it then and ask for help. Community does not encourage such questions.

Comment: File reading worked (thanks!), but then i got stuck with the dimensions and word reading. I just don't get how to first read an int with spaces between and then read the characters of the puzzle and then read the amount of words and last the actual words. The logic just isn't there for me yet. any help?